# What do the colors mean in Chrome Developer Tools Scope panel?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am curious why some variables are solid and some variables are half opacity. What is the difference between them? Both variations are available in the global scope.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Good question. I made an [issue](https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/issues/2803) to get this documented.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If the property is shown dimmed that means it's not enumerable. So it won't show up in when you loop through the object's properties:

Take the location object as an example:

[image: Location logged in console]

When enumerating the properties `toString`, `valueOf` and `__proto__` don't show up:

```
var keys = []; for (var key in location) { keys.push(key) }; console.log(keys)
-> ["replace", "assign", "hash", "search", "pathname", "port", "hostname", "host",  
"protocol", "origin", "href", "ancestorOrigins", "reload"]
```

---

You can use `propertyIsEnumerable` to find out if the property will show up when you loop over the object:

```
location.propertyIsEnumerable("search")
// true
location.propertyIsEnumerable("toString")
// false
```

By default all properties of an object are enumerable:

[image: post.title is enumerable]

But you can change that by using `defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(post, "author", {
     value: "John Doe",
     enumerable: false
});
```

When you log that object to the console the author property appears in a slightly lighter shade of purple.

(It seems the shorthand version doesn't have support for this formatting feature, but we can force DevTools to use the longer version for a small object using the `dir` function.)

[image: author property isn't enumerable]

Comment: Awesome detail! Thanks